# Post operator evaluation order

Tags: java, c++, post-increment

My friend and I came upon an interesting joke `C > C++` since he likes C over C++. However, I am curious as to the validity of executing that code segment. I ran and compiled

```
int C;
C = 1;std::cout << (C++ < C) << "\n";
C = 1;std::cout << (C < C++) << "\n";
C = 1;std::cout << (C++ > C) << "\n";
C = 1;std::cout << (C > C++) << "\n";
```

the output was 1 0 0 1 using C++98/C++11, and true, false, false, false for Java.

My question is how does the process of evaluation of these statement work? I get especially confused because `C++ < C` and `C > C++` contradict each other in Java, while staying consistent in C++, as well as the logic of `C++ < C`, where supposedly the left and right sides are equal or the left side is greater than the right.

Comment: Contradict each other how?

Comment: The C++ half of this question is a duplicate; some other languages define it.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior

Answer (score 2):

The result is undefined for C/C++ by the specification because the order of evaluation is not specified. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) for details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points